# C++. std::vector - не пойму, SFML. куча вопросов

Tags: c++, указатели, vector, sfml

Проясните пожалуйста. То что кладется в std::vector оно размещается в динамической памяти (то есть как при вызове new)?
Как вообще поместить объекты в динамическую память в вектор?

Вот например вектор с указателями

```
std::vector <Obj*> OBJ_Ptrs;
```

Если я туда понасоздаю их в стиле Obj o("id") и понакладу кучу этих самых Obj*, допустим они большие и сложные сами по себе, то они в динамическую память попадут?

Еще такая проблема с SFML. У меня лежит в векторе указатели на объекты, которые унаследованы от sf::Sprite, у такого объекта переопределен метод draw

```
void draw(sf::RenderTarget& rt)const  override;
void Obj::draw(sf::RenderTarget & rt) const
{
    rt.draw(*this); 
}
```

В самом Obj, есть указатели на спрайт, там на текстуру и тп, это все наследуется из спрайта.
Когда я манипулирую вектором из этих указателей на Obj, все нормально, а когда получаю элемент вектора, разыменовываю, и у него вызываю draw, то у этого obj (*this) ломаются указатели на текстуру. Это известный факт такой поломки текстуры в sfml, но я не пойму почему так у меня, я все через указатели делаю.

UPD. ну вроде с белыми текстурами разобрался. У меня был некий чужой ресурс-менеджер, в который я добавил функцию по получению тайлов, аналогично той что была, только с расчетом по индексу и размеру вырезкой, ну и поиском сначала большой текстуры в памяти, а не сразу из файла, но почему то перед возвращение шаред-указателя не клал его в мапу c шаред-указателями, так же как оригинальная функция из менеджера. ну и указатель наверное умирал, когда за скобки выходил. До конца механику работы умных ук. не понимаю еще.

Comment: Приведите минимальный компилируемый пример, демонстрирующий проблему. Я вот ничего не понял из написанного. И да, "такой проблемы в SFML" нет.

Comment: ну я сейчас уже кучу переворотил, но смысл тот же. как компилируемый будет если не заведется то пришлю. там просто не так мало присылать надо

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` хранит данные в памяти, динамически выделенной аллокатором. Аллокатор по умолчанию выделяет память при помощи `operator new()`, но можно также, например, выделять память на стеке, или при помощи `malloc`. Так или иначе, `vector` получает блок памяти и последовательно размещает в нём объекты, если блока памяти не хватает - запрашивает новый и размещает объекты уже в нём, а старый освобождает.

Таким образом, если вы просто создаёте `std::vector<Obj>` - вы получаете набор объектов в динамической памяти, при этом все они будут последовательно располагаться в одном блоке памяти. Но при добавлении нового объекта предыдущие объекты могут быть перемещены или копированы в другой блок памяти, что может привести в том числе к повреждению ресурсов. Если вы создаёте `std::vector<Obj*>` - в динамической памяти будут созданы только указатели, сами объекты созданы не будут, их нужно создавать самостоятельно при помощи new или умных указателей - и эти объекты уже гарантированно будут созданы в динамической памяти и не будут перемещаться при добавлении новых объектов.

Вот пример создания вектора объектов в динамической памяти при помощи умных указателей (вероятно, вам нужно именно это):

```
class Obj {
  // Для объектов с виртуальными функциями копирование может привести к проблемам. 
  // Возможно, именно из-за незапланированного копирования у вас возникли проблемы
  Obj(const Obj&) = delete; 

  virtual void call(){} 
  virtual ~Obj(){}
};
class Foo: public Obj {
  void call(){}
  ~Foo(){}
};

std::vector<std::uniqie_ptr<Obj>> vector;
vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Obj>());
vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());
for(auto&& obj: vector)
   obj->call();
```

Comment: Спасибо. "Если вы создаёте std::vector<Obj>* - в динамической памяти будут созданы только указатели" - а это не указатель на вектор с объектами? А что если мне нужно не просто создать объект Obj так std::make_unique<Obj>(), а еще и сделать Obj.SetTexture(). Это придется уже потом делать тогда? Каждый obj - это объект отличающейся текстурой от другого, позже может и id еще будут у них.

Comment: А может мне вообще list использовать для хранения, а не вектор?

Comment: не помогла указанная вами схема, белые спрайты правильного размера рисуются, но без текстуры

Comment: Поставьте пж звездочку в ответе в правильное место...

Comment: @gmax , `std::vector<Obj>*` - это ошибка. `std::list<Obj>` мало отличается от 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obj>>' (отличается скорость вставки и удаления), но он не может хранить объекты-наследники, всё-равно придется хранить список указателей. Можно сначала создать указатель, а потом поместить в вектор: `auto obj = std::make_unique<Foo>(); obj->setTexture(); vector.push_back(std::move(obj));`. Или можно получить ссылку на последний вставленный указатель через `vector.back()`.